# Is using the phrase "you and your team members' end" grammatically incorrect, or does it not sound like something a native English speaker would say?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, phrases

Earlier today, I wrote "Please let me know if this looks good on your and your team members' end" in an email, and was told that I should have said "Please let me know if this looks good on your team's end". Was the first way that I stated it grammatically incorrect, or was it grammatically correct but sounded strange?

Comment: I don't think there is an error. It may be a little wordy, but there's nothing wrong. It's perfectly understandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Billy says in a comment, there is no grammar error, but it is wordy. There's no need for "and your team members'" as "you" would  be understood in
context as the plural "you" meaning "you and your team".

"On your team's end" is also possible but doesn't really fix the problem of wordiness.

Answer (score -1):

As for me is correct because you included the person whom you're sending  to the team.if you said to look good on your team that shows that the person is not among them

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).